# Dynamic filtered named range in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, named-ranges

Is it possible to use a formula to have a dynamically filtered named range? Essentially, what I want to do is have a data validation dropdown containing filtered results. The data would be like as follows:

```
Name    Filter
Steve   TRUE
Mike    FALSE
Bob TRUE
Jim TRUE
Billy   FALSE
Jose    FALSE
```

I would want the dropdown to only show the names that have "TRUE" in the filter field (e.g. Steve, Bob, and Jim). It seems like the new FILTER function would accomplish this pretty easily, but unfortunately that is not available to me at the moment.

Comment: Yeah this is possible,,, use INDEX & MATCH combination to  filter multiple row on criteria,, then Name the filtered range and use it as source with drop down. Or you may think for dependent drop down also!

Answer (score 2):

I made a sample as your data, then you could type：
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(ISERROR(FIND("TRUE",($B$2:$B$100))),"",ROW($B$2:$B$100)),ROW(A1))),""), press Ctrl, Shift and Enter at the same time. Then pull down the cell. Hope this information could help you.

In addition, thanks for Rajesh S's reminders and help.

[image]

Comment: Your formula needs little correction,, add `IFERROR` since formula returns `#NUM!` error if no value,, also OP need the names to  attach with Drop down,, (make Col C a Dyanamic Name Range & add with Drop down),, edit your post & complete it.